# Extract same column from two CSV files, and merge it

Tags: python, csv, compare

So I've got two CSV files that I'm trying to compare and get the results of the item has same column. The first file, a.csv is like shown below:

```
name          pubmedid    country 
legge          3064733      U.S
legge          3034763      U.S
Hoffman        2888122      NA
```

and second CSV is b.csv which looks like:

```
name          pubmedid    country  category
Sung           3454733      U.K    European
NA             2035763      U.S    American
Hoffman        3194992      NA     Asian
legge          3064733      U.S    African-American
```

I want to extract the information from the columns that are common to the two files

than merge it to one CSV file
,and remove all the row that contain "NA"

so result what I want will be looks like:

```
name          pubmedid    country 
legge          3064733      U.S
legge          3034763      U.S
Sung           3454733      U.K   
legge          3064733      U.S
```

than I want to write this result on c.csv file.

How can I do this?

I'm trying to find way to do this without using pandas, because I still didn't fully understood how does pandas work, and try to skip row that contain 'NA' while reading origian a, b csv file but I failed... is it better to remove row that contain NA after merge two files together?

Comment: Which common information from the columns of the two files you are looking for?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma I'm trying to extract column that both involved in a.csv and b.csv...a.csv doesn't have category column, so I want mege both csv from name to country, than remove row that contain NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Using pandas:**

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv', sep="\s+")
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv', sep="\s+")

df = pd.concat([df1.dropna(), df2[["name", "pubmedid", "country"]].dropna()])
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
    name  pubmedid country
0  legge   3064733     U.S
1  legge   3034763     U.S
0   Sung   3454733     U.K
3  legge   3064733     U.S
```

To save this `df` to csv file,

```
df.to_csv("c.csv", index=False)
```

---

**2. Without using pandas:**

Use:

```
import csv

with open("a.csv", "r") as fa, open("b.txt", "r") as fb, open("c.csv", "w") as fc:
    writer = csv.writer(fc, delimiter=' ')

    reader = csv.reader(fa, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        if "NA" not in line:
            writer.writerow(line)

    next(fb) # skip header
    reader = csv.reader(fb, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        if "NA" not in line:
            writer.writerow(line[:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for you kind reply, but is there other possible way to solve this kind of problem without using pandas module?

Comment: Probably but by using pandas this would be much more easier.

Comment: I aleady tried similar one with 2nd solution, but it included category in result, and didn't skip line that has "Na" .

Comment: @goldenasian Are you sure? What's your delimiter in csv files `a` and `b`?

Comment: pretty sure that it is ' '

Comment: I solved it it was much simpler than what I imagined thanks for your help!